# php array: not showing proper values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php code. I am just trying out to define and get array. The below is the code.

```
 <?php
      $query = 'summer';
      $query['jink'] = array( 1,4,5,6 );
      var_dump($query);
      var_dump($query['jink']);
 ?>
```

var_dump returns:

```
string 'Aummer' (length=6)
string 'A' (length=6)
```

The output is not as expected. it should give something from (1,4,5,6)

Comment: No, the output is parse error.  Once fixed it is another parse error, then undefined function.

Comment: The code as you show it here will not run. Too many syntax errors.

Comment: You have `$query['jink'` inside your `var_dump` (missing closing brace). You also left off the semi-colon on `$query = 'summer'` Is that a typo in this post or in the real code?

Comment: This is total mummpitz! http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a5b57e8155bc26f8c7225fb2cc8bd7395e363dbb.

Comment: Also its `var_dump` with an underscore.

Comment: sorry edited. I wanted to know some thing more related to the array.

Comment: Turn on PHP's error reporting and display errors on screen: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script. Always use this when developing code. There's a lot here PHP will complain about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed your errors in order to show the issue:

```
 $query = 'summer';
 $query['jink'] = array( 1,4,5,6 );
```

`$query` is a string "*summer*" so `['jink']`, not being a valid string offset is converted to 0 and it accesses the first character of "*summer*".  Also, `array( 1,4,5,6 )` is not a string it is `Array` and the "*A*" from `Array` is assigned to offset 0 of "*summer*" yielding "*Aummer*":

```
 var_dump($query);
```

Now again you are getting string offset 0 which is "*A*" from "*Aummer*":

```
 var_dump($query['jink']);
```

If you use error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

You will see:

> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'jink' in file line
>
> PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in file line
>
> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'jink' in file line

Comment: thank you. you gave right explanation about the output coming.

Answer (score 0):

What you maybe want is:

```
$query = ['summer'];
$query['jink'] = [1,4,5,6 ];
var_dump($query);
var_dump($query['jink']);
```

## PHP Sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50f22fb5de571baf5978ab37e8cd645ec174125e.

Comment: I tried yours. It gives the same output A and Aummer. Where is the A coming from.

Comment: You mean the one in the comment? I thought as @AbraCadaver posted and gave a solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is that you set the `$query` as a string then turn it into an array.You should simply edit `$query = 'summer'` to `$query[] = 'summer'` as this [link](https://eval.in/199037) shows.